# traefik: use PathPrefixStrip and PathPrefix together

Tags: traefik

Using trafix w/ docker backend, I would like to match all URLs of form `/manage/users/api...` and map them into `/api...`. I tried:

```
traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/manage/users;PathPrefix:/api;
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 10):

The following works:

```
traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/manage/users/api;AddPrefix:/api;
```